# Associations - Foreign Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two objects:

```
create_table "conditions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "condition_category_id"
 end

create_table "condition_categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
end
```

I am trying to list my conditions with the condition category name in another column. However since I named it with an underscore I am a bit confused on how to properly set up the association. I noticed that the model was rewritten to ConditionCategory, but I still can't get it working right.

Here is my model for Condition

```
class Condition < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ConditionCategory'
end
```

And on my view

```
<td><%= condition.category.name %></td>
```

Relatively new to rails so any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

1.As **@gregates** suggested you should add `foreign_key` to your association in your `Condition` model

```
class Condition < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ConditionCategory',
    foreign_key: 'condition_category_id'
end
```

**OR**

2.Just modify your `Condition` model like this.Which is very simple and precise.

```
class Condition < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :condition_category
end
```

And in your view,you have to change like this

```
<td><%= condition.condition_category.name %></td>
```

to get the name of the `condition_category` associated with that `condition`

Answer (score 1):

See the [`foreign_key` option for the `belongs_to` relation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key). The foreign key is expected to match the name of the *association*, not the `class_name` (when they differ). So you need to specify both:

```
belongs_to :category, class_name: 'ConditionCategory',
                      foreign_key: 'condition_category_id'
```

Alternatively, you can rename the foreign key column in the database to `category_id`.